# Why does NestJS with Swagger report all my DTO properties as required?

Tags: swagger, nestjs

I have this DTO class defined.

```js
import { ApiProperty } from "@nestjs/swagger"

export class FormDTO {
    @ApiProperty()
    id: string

    @ApiProperty()
    type: string

    @ApiProperty()
    fieldValues?: Record<string, unknown>

    @ApiProperty()
    parentFormId?: string
}
```

I expected that the generated OpenAPI spec would indicate that `fieldValues` and `parentFormId` would be optional, but they are required.

[image]

According to the example in the docs [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/types-and-parameters) they should be optional. What am I missing?

The only method using that DTO looks like this, but I didn't think it would matter:

```js
@Post(":id")
createForm(@Body() createFormDto: FormDTO) {
    if (this.formService.hasForm(createFormDto.id)) {
        throw new ConflictException(
            undefined,
            `A form with the id ${createFormDto.id} already exists.`
        )
    }
    return this.formService.createOrUpdateForm(createFormDto)
}
```

If it matters, here is the code for the `DocumentBuilder`

```js
const config = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle("API")
    .setDescription(
        "description."
    )
    .setVersion("1.0")
    .addBearerAuth(
        {
            type: "http",
            scheme: "bearer",
            bearerFormat: "JWT",
            description: "Paste a valid access token here."
        },
        JWTGuard.name
    )
    .build()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

because that's what `@ApiProperty()` does

Instead, use [`@ApiPropertyOptional()`](https://github.com/nestjs/docs.nestjs.com/pull/2183) for optional fields.